# How to send a path directory as a parameter to a php script?

Tags: php, linux, shell

I need to give a path to a folder as an input to a php script so that my php script will do certain things depending on the path. From the linux terminal (Debian), I run my program with the command:

```
php /path/name/example.php
```

If I write:

```
php /path/name/example.php pwd
```

I would expect it to pass in the present working directory into my php script but it doesn't. I `echo argv[1]` which is what is passed into the script, and it only prints out "pwd", instead of the directory. How can I send the directory as a parameter to my script?

*ANSWERED*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) using `$()` or  back ticks.

```
$php prog.php $(pwd)
```

The `$()` executes the command, (`pwd` here) and pass the output as argument to the php script.